# Hiding and showing Panel during runtime

Tags: java, swing, panel

I'm trying to show and hide a panel during run time, so I call the methods from another class:

```
Con.Action(1);
```

to this method:

```
 public void Action(int whichPanel) {
    if (whichPanel == 1) {
        if (frame.Data.isVisible()) {
            frame.Data.setVisible(false);
            // frame.splitPaneSec.remove(frame.Data);
        } else {
            System.out.println(".....");

            //frame.Data.setVisible(false);
            frame.Data.setVisible(true);
            //frame.getContentPane().validate();
                            //frame.revalidate();
                            //frame.repaint();
            //frame.pack();
        }
    }
```

So far i'm able to hide a panel but I can't show it again once I hidden it.
I've tried many ways some of them are commented out.
Any help is appreciated, cheers

Comment: same issue with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: *"I'm trying to show and hide a panel during run time"*  Why?  It would typically make more sense to either use a `CardLayout` or enable/disable controls as per relevance to the current data or options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was because after setting the component back to `visible` 
it was required to `GUIClass.splitPane.setDividerLocation(157);`

Answer (score 0):

I think I would rather remove and add it back.

```
parent.remove(dataPanel);
parent.validate();
parent.repaint();

parent.add(dataPanel);
parent.validate();
parent.repaint();
```

Comment: I've tried what you suggested but doesn't respond to add, it will remove but not add it back.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommed you to use enums for Tasks like this:

```
public void Action(int whichPanel) {
    if (whichPanel == 1) {} 
//Better;
public void Action(enumType myPanel){
    if(myPanel == enumType.LoginScreen){}
```

with `

```
public enum enumType
{
    LoginScreen,EditScreen //...
}`
```

You can hide and show Enums if you perfom the setVisible method directly on the Panel you want to show:

```
public void showLoginScreen()
{
    loginPanel.setVisible(true);
    registerMenu.setVisible(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class HidePanel extends JFrame {

    private static final int PANEL_HEIGHT = 50;
    private static final int INITIAL_PANEL_WIDTH = 50;
    private static final int TIMER_INTERVAL = 1;
    private static final int PIXEL_DELTA = 2;
    private Dimension panelDimension = new Dimension(INITIAL_PANEL_WIDTH, PANEL_HEIGHT);
    private int vertOffset = -PANEL_HEIGHT;
    private Timer showTimer = new HidePanel.ShowPanelTimer();
    private Timer hideTimer = new HidePanel.HidePanelTimer();

    static JLayeredPane lpane = new JLayeredPane();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();


    public HidePanel() {
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        setLayout(null);

        panel.setBounds(1200, 50, 100, 600);
        panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Hide"));
        panel.add(new JButton("Click Me"));
        lpane.add(panel);//, //new Integer(0), 0);

        add(panel);

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                final int height = e.getY() - 100 ;

                if (height < 50 && !showTimer.isRunning() && !panel.isVisible()) {
                    showTimer.start();
                } else if (height > PANEL_HEIGHT + 5 && !hideTimer.isRunning() && panel.isVisible()) {
                    hideTimer.start();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        HidePanel h = new HidePanel();
        h.setSize(1350, 700);
        h.setVisible(true);
        h.add(lpane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private void positionPanel(final int offset) {
        int panelWidth = getWidth();

        System.out.println(" offset = " + offset);

        panelDimension.setSize(panelWidth, PANEL_HEIGHT);

        //panel.setBounds(insets.left, offset + insets.top, size.width, size.height);
    }

    private class ShowPanelTimer extends Timer implements ActionListener {

        ShowPanelTimer() {
            super(TIMER_INTERVAL, null); 
            addActionListener(this);
        }

        public void start() {
            vertOffset = -PANEL_HEIGHT;
            panel.setVisible(true);
            super.start();
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (vertOffset <= 0) {
                positionPanel(vertOffset);
            } else {
                showTimer.stop();
            }

            vertOffset += PIXEL_DELTA;
        }
    }

    private class HidePanelTimer extends Timer implements ActionListener {

        HidePanelTimer() {
            super(TIMER_INTERVAL, null); 
            addActionListener(this);
        }

        public void stop() {
            panel.setVisible(false);
            super.stop(); 
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (vertOffset >= (-PANEL_HEIGHT)) {
                vertOffset -= PIXEL_DELTA;
                positionPanel(vertOffset);
            } else {
                hideTimer.stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```